# Screen went white on Acer Aspire laptop, shows only logo and then white takes over

Tags: laptop, display, linux-mint, acer-aspire

Out of nowhere, my Acer Aspire laptop's screen went white and then I rebooted it and it only shows Aspire logo, and then goes white and then it boots into Linux Mint and for a split second shows Linux Mint logo before white again.

Then, after like a minute and some, the screen begins to darken and it'll show grey and black lines and become totally normal for two seconds before white happens again and it keeps going like that, white then normal after a minute or so.

Everything works normal, logged into the system and it shows everything okay in those two seconds before it whites out again. I have no idea what happened or how.

Also tried to reset contrast and brightness values to default from console at startup but it did nothing. I have yet to try it on an external monitor.

UPDATE: Tested with an external monitor, it works normal, so I'm guessing problem is in the cables to screen from motherboard? I should open it soon and see what I can do.

Comment: Either the screen itself is failing, the cable for the screen is failing, or the motherboard has an issue. It's possible it's simply a loose connection between the cable and the motherboard, however display cables usually have a meaty metal connector that creates a tight connection between the cable and the motherboard. If Acer doesn't provide a disassembly manual, there's likely a video on YoutTube showing how to disassemble it. Before doing anything, run hardware diagnostics, which are usually accessible from the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot screen, or from with the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings.

Comment: Before anything else, try booting from a live Mint USB. If that works *without issue*, then the problem is either the internal drive (for example, a failing SSD might become read-only, aborting the boot process), or OS issues, i.e., Mint needs to be repaired. *However,* if the issue persists when booting from USB, it is indeed a hardware failure.